# Semi side bar collapse without hiding the title

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to semi-hide the side bar from shiny app.

Using this function on the body:

```
tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('sidebar-mini');"))
```

I got this result:

[image: Hide side-bar]

Is there a way to hide the sidebar, without hiding the title, just modifying this script ?

[image: Right way]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a short title, it will be displayed when the sidebar is collapsed :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = tagList(
        tags$span(
          class = "logo-mini", "Short"
        ),
        tags$span(
          class = "logo-lg", "My Long Title"
        )
      )
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('sidebar-mini');"))
    ),
    title = "Dashboard example"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
}
```

Normal:

[image]

Collapsed:

[image]

Comment: Tried this but both titles are pased to each other, why?

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you have a built in CSS class called "hide".

`tags$script(HTML("$('.sidebar-mini #YOUR_SIDEBAR_ID').addClass('hide');"))`

IF you want to get fancy then do things like absolute position -9999 and opacity 0, then "reveal it" when needed...

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I wonder what kind of "hide" class are you referring to here. Mind to illustrate a bit more? Thank you